# output batch results to excel

Tags: excel, windows, batch-file

I am new to this whole batch scripting thing but am really getting into it. I've been using a batch scrip and outputting constant ping results along with a timestamp to a .txt file but would like to output to a .xlsx instead. This is the script I have been using.

```
@echo off

title Google Ping

mode 12,1

:start

set DT=%date:/=-%

timeout /t 30

echo %time% %date% >> C:\Users\Bradley\Desktop\Logs\google_log%DT%.txt

ping -n 1 8.8.8.8 >> C:\Users\Bradley\Desktop\Logs\google_log%DT%.txt

goto start
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to read and write an Excel file with a pure batch file. You can do it with Vbscript and Powershell.  But the easiest option I feel is just writing it out to a csv file. Usually CSV files default to opening with Excel.

```
@echo off
title Google Ping
echo date,time,ip,bytes,pingtime,ttl>pinglog.csv

:begin
FOR /F "tokens=3-6 delims=: " %%G IN ('ping -n 1 8.8.8.8^|find /i "reply from"') DO (
    SET ip=%%G
    SET %%H
    SET ping%%I
    SET %%J
)
>>pinglog.csv echo %date%,%time%,%ip%,%bytes%,%pingtime%,%TTL%
timeout /t 10 >nul

GOTO begin
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar myself.  I make a *.txt* file with:

```
C:
cd\Users\garys\Documents\My Spreadsheets
dir /s /b  > %userprofile%\Desktop\directry\SpreadsheetFiles.txt
```

and then get it into Excel with:

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim s As String, Textline As String, i As Long
    Dim RC As Long

    s = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    RC = Rows.Count
    Range("B2:F" & RC).Clear
    Range("A2:A" & RC).ClearContents

    Close #1
    Open s For Input As #1

    i = 2
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, Textline
        Cells(i, "C").Value = Textline
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

The material goes into column **C**, leaving room at the top for a header.